# Rust - Are slices objects mutables by default?

Tags: rust

Hello fellow Rustaceans!
How it is possible that i can write that in Rust:

```
let mut v : Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
v.push(0);
v.push(1);
v.push(2);
let s = &v;
print!("{:?} - ", s); // will output "[0, 1, 2]"
let s = &v[1..];
println!("{:?}", s); // will screen "[1, 2]"
```

Normaly variables are immutable by default, no ?
And here i can change the value of the slice (s)
but normaly s is declared than variable with "let" ?
what's wrong ?

Comment: You don't change `s`: you declare another `s`. Reusing a variable name (which shadows the first one) is totally valid in Rust but isn't akin to mutation.

Comment: This is strange comportment because if i inject the first "s" in a threaded function ( the output take some seconds to be disponible) and the second (re) affectation "s" in another threaded function and i would sum (by example) the two output, the result will be wrong !
however perhaps rust will block this two affectation on compilation ?

Comment: But your answer is fully logic and comprehensive, i think that is the compiler will block the this two affectation on compilation. thanks to you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you're making a new variable called `s`. Up to renaming, your code is equivalent to

```
let mut v : Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
v.push(0);
v.push(1);
v.push(2);
let s = &v;
print!("{:?} - ", s); // will output "[0, 1, 2]"
let my_unrelated_s_variable = &v[1..];
println!("{:?}", my_unrelated_s_variable); // will screen "[1, 2]"
```

The two `s` you declared are, as far as the Rust compiler is concerned, unrelated variables. In fact, we could even give the second one a different type.

```
let s = &v;
let s = 42; // This one's an integer, but it's fine
```

This sort of shadowing is very common in Rust when we want to augment a particular value but want to respect immutability, as it guarantees we aren't actually changing anything in memory while allowing us the convenience of reusing variable names. For example, I often find myself doing things like this.

```
fn example(input: &str) {
  let input = some_complicated_parsing_step(input)?;
  ...
}
```

The argument `input` is a string, and I want to convert it to something (maybe parse it as JSON, maybe read an integer from it, etc.). Once I do that, I have no use for the original string anymore, and it's reasonable to call the result of parsing `input`, as it is still the input I was given, just in a different form now.

Comment: This is strange comportment because if i inject the first "s" in a threaded function ( the output take some seconds to be disponible) and the second (re) affectation "s" in another threaded function and i would sum (by example) the two output, the result will be wrong !
however perhaps rust will block this two affectation on compilation ?

Comment: But your answer is fully logic and comprehensive, i think that is the compiler will block the this two affectation on compilation. thanks to you !

Comment: fn example(input: &str) {
      let input = some_complicated_parsing_step(input)?;
      ...
    }


What you describe here is called "transtyping" in other programming languages
that's right ?
Thanks !